# Merge [http-chunked], [chunked], and [chunked-encoding]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonyms

These three tags refer to the same thing:

- [http-chunked](/questions/tagged/http-chunked)
- [chunked](/questions/tagged/chunked)
- [chunked-encoding](/questions/tagged/chunked-encoding)

Should they be merged?

Comment: Perhaps all merged into [tag:transfer-encoding]?  Might be going a bit far, as there *are* other transfer encoding used, albeit infrequently.